# raydium clmm pool swap

Tags: solana-program, rpc, python, liquiditypool, raydium

I can perform token swap transactions in Raydium with Python. but I don't know how to do this on a token in the clmm pool. I can collect the keys from the Raydium API in the normal AMM pool and perform the transaction. But I guess clmm pools don't have keys like amm. I would be very happy if anyone can help me how to do this.Doesn't matter python or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

CLMM pools do have a pool ID. It's always better to parse the data but you can also use the Raydium API to quickly collect CLMM Pool keys.

> https://api.raydium.io/v2/ammV3/ammPools
> "id"